# Django makemigrations doesn't work

Tags: python, django

Something wrong went with Django makemigrations, the code like below:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, verbose_name=u'')
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=u'')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name=u'')

    objects = UserManager()
```

When I run `python manage.py makemigrations` , the field `is_staff` doesn't show up in the migration file. I don't know why this field disappears. But if I change the name to `is_aa`, it shows right.

The migration file is:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

initial = True

dependencies = [
    ('auth', '0008_alter_user_username_max_length'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='User',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
            ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='last login')),
            ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.', verbose_name='superuser status')),
            ('nickname', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, verbose_name='\u6635\u79f0')),
            ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='\u662f\u5426\u6709\u6548')),
            ('groups', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Group', verbose_name='groups')),
            ('user_permissions', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Permission', verbose_name='user permissions')),
        ],
        options={
            'db_table': 'user',
        },
        managers=[
            ('objects', apps.api.user.models.UserManager()),
        ],
    ),
```

Comment: just delete `property` is_staff

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project) apply to your situation?

Comment: yeah, property and field are duplicated, just deletee the property

Answer (score 4):

```
is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False)
```

and add this to your model:

```
def get_group_permissions(self, obj=None): 
    return self.is_staff
```

Use this, as `is_staff` already exists with `PermissionMixin`, thus the conflict happens.

Comment: I don't see `is_staff ` in `PermissionMixin `, and it doesn't work  neither.

Comment: drop your migrations files once and try again

Comment: is your table there?? try to drop all the tables, then migrate, then makemigrations

Comment: the table has been dropped

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147351/discussion-between-zimmer-and-exprator).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to the model:

```
class Meta:
    db_table = 'User'
    managed = True
```

With "managed = True" you are saying to django that he need to manage all migrations.

After this update your app (if is an external app)
and run

```
python manage.py makemigrations user
python manage.py showmigrations user (to check if the migration is now correct)
python manage.py migrate user
```